# mysql group by and count rows problem

Tags: sql, mysql

let's say mysql is something like this

```
select x,y 
from xx 
group by y
```

i want to know how many rows that select will get, i tried to use count but it will n't return all results since i'm using group by.

how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to know how many rows are in each group?  Or how many rows are in all groups?  Or how many groups?

Comment: all rows that this select returns

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can wrap your query like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
  (select x,y  
    from xx  
    group by y) sub;
```

Comment: Any idea how this could be done if the MySQL server in question does not allow subqueries?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a table with the content below:

```
 -------------------
| ID | NAME | GROUP |
+-------------------+
| 1  |  A   |  1    |
+-------------------+
| 2  |  B   |  2    |
+-------------------+
| 3  |  C   |  2    |
+-------------------+
| 4  |  D   |  3    |
+-------------------+
| 5  |  E   |  1    |
+-------------------+
| 6  |  F   |  3    |
+-------------------+
```

The following self LEFT JOIN counts the number of distinct values in GROUP.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table AS t1
LEFT JOIN table AS t2 ON t2.GROUP = t1.GROUP AND t2.ID > t1.ID
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

What this query does is find out, for each group, the element with the highest id.

Answer (score 0):

You can check my ans https://stackoverflow.com/a/36449637/2439715

```
SELECT 
    sum(1) as counttotal
FROM (
    Your query with group by operator
) as T
```